# Given a solution $y(z)$ of a linear ODE, what is the general name for other independent solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

It is a [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) fact that solutions of a linear ODE form a vector space whose dimensions equals the order of the differential equation.

Given $y(z)$ is a solution of a given ODE of order $n$, how does one generally refer to other $n-1$ solutions? Complimentary, associated, adjoint, dual?

If possible, please provide a reference (wikipedia will do) where such a terminology is being used.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A set of $n$ independent solutions is traditionally called a "fundamental set of solutions" ([link 1](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FundamentalSetsofSolutions.aspx) [link 2](http://www.math.psu.edu/srikrish/math251/notes/fundamentalsols.pdf) [link 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378487/finding-fundamental-set-of-solution-of-higher-order-differential-equation)) to the differential equation. However, there is not really a standard way to refer to the rest.

You could say "$n-1$ other solutions to form a fundamental set", or use terms of Linear Algebra and say something like "extend this solution to a basis for the space of solutions" (or invoke some inner product and speak of a basis for the orthogonal complement of some nontrivial solution).